# Filter dictionary with value as array of an arrays in swift programmatically

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

I have the following dictionary and I would like to filter as follows

```
var emojiDict = [String: [[String]]]()
emojiDict = ["key one":[["item name 1", "item photo 1"],["item name 2", "item photo 2"], ["item name 3", "item photo 3"]],

"key two":[["item name 1", "item photo 1"],["item name 2", "item photo 2"], ["item name 3", "item photo 3"]],

"key three":[["item name 4", "item photo 1"],["item name 2", "item photo 2"], ["item name 3", "item photo 3"]]]
```

I would like to filter the above dictionary with search term `item name 1` and return the following results

```
emojiDict = ["key one":[["item name 1", "item photo 1"]],

"key two":[["item name 1", "item photo 1"]]]
```

I tried below solution but it didn't work

```
let searchText = "item name 1"

let emojiDictFiltered = emojiDict.mapValues { $0.filter { $0.hasPrefix(searchText) } }.filter { !$0.value.isEmpty }
```

I kindly request for your assistance.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to filter the dictionary based on search results. I would like to return the results that contains the search term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `reduce(into:)` to filter out the matches

```
let filtered = emojiDict.reduce(into: [String: [[String]]]()) {
    let result = $1.value.filter { $0.contains(searchTerm)}
    if result.isEmpty == false {
        $0[$1.key] = result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me try it out

Comment: @ashwyllsolutions I have modified my answer

Comment: Thankyou for response Joakim.  However, Both the solutions you have provided return  dictionary with keys but empty values.

Comment: Not for me when testing on _your_ sample using _your_ search term.

Comment: Okey let me try once more may be I could be making certain errors

Comment: Thanks Joan Danielson, Finally I managed to come up with a solution from the previous answer you gave. I have tried your solutions but didn't work for me

Comment: Both our answers works fine for me in and the only thing is a bit different is that you use an optional search variable, did you try my answer in the same way using  `searchText!`?

Comment: I saw where I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have managed to solve the issue I'm facing

```
var emojiDictFiltered = [String: [[String]]]()

for (key, value) in emojiDict {
            let result = value.filter { (dataArray:[String]) -> Bool in
                return dataArray.filter({ (string) -> Bool in
                    return string.contains(searchText!)
                }).count > 0
            }
            
            if result.isEmpty == false {
                emojiDictFiltered[key] = result
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't `let` declare `emojiDictFiltered` since it is a variable.

Comment: Sorry, it is a copying error